# Constructing Polyhedron from given areas faces.

Tags: area, surfaces, polyhedra

I want to visualize a set of data as polyhedrons in 3d space. Imagine set A includes areas of such polyhedron's faces. I assume the first step is to check if there exist a polyehdron by making sure each area is larger than the sum of other areas. Then we can perhaps find sets of all normal vectors satisfying such polyhedrons by solving:

∑ Ai.Ni=0

I do not know what comes next. Assuming we will settle with a unique set of N (for example one that provides the maximum valume), what are the next steps in constructing the Polyhedron? Also what is the best method to find coordinates of vertices/edges to further interact with the resulted Polyhedron?

On a side note: for designers like me with undergraduate background in Mathematics, what programming language do you recommend to visualize data and models built on mathematical algorithms?

Thanks.

Comment: I have not at all a general idea. But what I would advise you to do is to solve first the case of a tetrahedron with 4 given area faces. Once this case is solved, why not proceed by creating new faces one by one by " edges-choping" ?

Comment: Asked simultaneously [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280921/6094). I posted an answer [there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/280924/6094) before I noticed it here.